# Differenciate tablet/smartphone and touch-screen computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchscreen

I'm developping a website that is offering a different navigation depending on if the user is browsing on a Smartphone (with touch screen) or on a computer.
Actually, the check is done through `Modernizr.touch` but I want touch-screen computers to act like others.

Does someone has an idea of how to reach that ?

Comment: If you want to detect **mobile** devices, why are you checking for it using **touch** criteria? Those two groups are not the same (as you mentioned is the case with touch-screen computers). Or, arguably, non-touch mobile devices.

Comment: I didn't explained well. I want to detect mobile touch-screen.

Comment: That would be the same as any devices that is both touch-enabled *and* mobile? You already have the touch-enabled check; just add the check for mobile devices to the selection criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

For detecting touch devices(including touchscreen monitor)

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
if(is_touch_device){
   //code for touch devices
}
```

for only detecting mobile devices:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 //code for touch devices
}
```

Comment: This question is on how to specifically **not** include certain touch devices. OP is trying to make a split between mobile/non-mobile, rather than touch/no-touch.

Comment: @Flater: if you look carefully then OP wants to distinguish touch monitor devices with normal desktop. This should work for all touch devices.

Comment: `Actually, the check is done through Modernizr.touch but I want touch-screen computers to act like others.` => From what I understand from this, touch-enabled computers are being registered as touch devices, which is what OP is trying to prevent from happening. The touch-enabled check is working as intended, but OP wants to make a selection based on *mobile* criteria rather than *touch* (or a combination of both. Either way, the point is that you can't use touch-compatibility as a selection for all mobile devices, since touch-enabled computers will be flagged as such as well.)

Comment: @Flater:ooh..second solution should work in that case.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to prevent touch-screen computers to act like touch-screen mobiles. I'll try your way combining touch-screen and mobile detection.

Thanks !

Comment: So cannot have an (e.g.) andriod tablet?